# How to remove the footer from a theme

Tags: footer

I am new to wordpress and I just install version 5.0.3and I installed Consult theme.

At the button of page,I am getting this message:

```
The-Consult By Themeruler.
```

How can I remove it from the pages?

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't a simple button you can push (unless there's a special one the theme developer created), but it can most likely be done via some basic theme tweaking.

First, make a child theme. There are lots of tutorials about how to do that.

Second, modify the child theme. Two options for this:

- hide the message via CSS: Find the CSS class for some enclosing HTML tag (there are several ways to determine that), and hide it via a CSS `display:none`. One drawback is that there's a risk Google might be unhappy with the page hiding things.
- customize the footer: Copy `footer.php` from the parent theme to the child theme. Edit the copy and remove the text you don't want, plus perhaps any enclosing now-empty HTML tags. One drawback is that if you later install an updated version of the parent theme, the child theme will still be using a modified version of the old footer.

Also, the generic WordPress themes have a similar footer message, which many people want to remove. So a web search for 'remove proudly powered by WordPress' should find lots of tutorials. Your situation is probably almost the same.

Answer (score -1):

There are a million ways to do this but this is the easiest.

In the admin, go to Appearance > Custimize > Additional CSS and add the following CSS, then hit publish.

```
.footer_btm_left {display: none;}
```

Refresh your site and that text should be gone.

Note: This will remove the text but leave the black box empty.  If you want to remove the entire black box add the following CSS.

```
.site-info {display: none;}
```

Comment: where is the text?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: changing CSS hide the text, but where it is, so I can remove it from the source or change it.

Comment: Did you read my answer above?  Read it, then do what it says, then you wont have the "text"

Comment: I read it and did it, it changes the ccs and make it footer display to none, but is dosn't remove it from the site. What if I want to change it?

Comment: You question was "How can I remove it from the pages?" not how can I change it.

Comment: to change it you would have to go into the template files, probably footer.php